# How can I alter all views inside a MySQL schema and change the SQL SECURITY from DEFINER to INVOKER?

Tags: mysql

I am using a MYSQL database and have a bunch of views that were created with SQL SECURITY as DEFINER. But I need to modify all of them to INVOKER.

How can I write a query that will modify the SQL SECURITY of all existing views and change them from DEFINER to INVOKER?

Also, is there something that I can do to the user account in order to make it INVOKER by default?

Comment: You must recreate all views with needed attribute value.

Comment: @Akina All right. Then is there a way to set the default settings so that all new views are created with invoker? Perhaps I could work on the prevention instead of the cure next time.

Comment: Anything that is not explicitly specified can be anything. Always specify all the attribute values of objects, if you need them to have specific values.

Comment: @Akina But there must be a way to have all views created with "INVOKER" by default. It doesn't make sense that MySQL would have "DEFINER" by default and unchangeable if the creation query doesn't specify anything. There must be a way to change it.

Comment: *There must be a way to change it.* I do not see the way other than create your own MySQL... "... with blackjack and hookers." (© Bender, Futurama)